# Is 1-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test a special case of 2-sample one?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579661/is-1-sample-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-a-special-case-of-2-sample-one) before on MSE. It seems to me that I'm unlikely to receive any answer. So I post it here. As long as I get an answer from either site, I will make an update for them.

---

I'm reading Kolmogorov–Smirnov test from [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

1. One-sample case

> [image]
>   [image]

2. Two-sample case

> [image]

I try to deduce the one-sample test from two-sample test by choosing $m$ and the second sample $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_m)$ such that $$D_{n, m}=\sup _{x}\left|F_{1, n}(x)-F_{2, m}(x)\right| = D_{n}=\sup _{x}\left|F_{n}(x)-F(x)\right|$$

I'm unable to make $F_{2, m}= F$.

---

**My questions:**

Is it possible to deduce 1-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test as a special case of 2-sample one? If yes, how to do it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: $F_{2,m}$ has uncertainty about the population CDF. $F$ has absolute certainty. Why do you expect to get $F$ from $F_{2,m}$?

Comment: @Dave that's just my attempt to solve this question and it fails.

Comment: What is the question you're trying to solve, deriving the one-sample test as a special case of the two-sample?

Comment: @Dave, that's exactly my question. I edited my question to be more specific.